# how to use multiple insert in sql navigator

Tags: sql, oracle

i am new to sql and i am trying to make a simple to use insert for every day use,
i have a table(matrix) that holds the connection between 3 variables ,
in most cases i have to insert or update the matrix but each insert is multiplied because of the matrix, i have made a simple example :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
where col1='A'
and col2 in ('1G','2F','3Q')
and col3 ='B'
/
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A','1G','B');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A','2F','B');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A','3Q','B');
```

the output table  will be

```
A   1G  B
A   2F  B
A   3Q  B
```

and in the more complex cases

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
where col1='A'
and col2 in ('1G','2F','3Q')
and col3 in ('B','C')
/
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A','1G','B');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A','2F','B');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A','3Q','B');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A','1G','C');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A','2F','C');
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A','3Q','C');
```

the output table  will be

```
A   1G  B
A   2F  B
A   3Q  B
A   1G  C
A   2F  C
A   3Q  C
```

is there a way to make an insert that will look like this or have similar functionality
for example A :

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A',in ('1G',2F','3Q'),'B');
```

and for example b :

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('A',in ('1G',2F','3Q'),in ('B','C'));
```

i usually use about 100 new values at a time in each column  that is multiplied because  of the matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a select and an insert statement.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table_x
WHERE col1='A'
AND col2 in ('1G','2F','3Q')
AND col3 ='B'
```

To do that table_x will need to contain all of the values that you want.  If you are asking for a way to write an insert statement that builds a 'table' of values in line using constants then no you can't do that.